# How to manage upcoming holidays in Angular Ngrx?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a state that includes the list of holiday items for specified year. For ex: If the selected year is 2019, I dispatch the load action to list the holidays and update the state. I've also options to add, remove or update the holiday. On every action I've specific action. Now the problem comes in when I try to show coming holidays on a widget. Due to I want to show all holidays from now to 3 months after the holiday might be between 2019-2020. What should I have to do now? Do I need to create a new state?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the holidays in one list.
With selectors you can filter holidays based on date ranges.

Comment: It will be increase the response time. Mostly you want only current year's data. Instead I use two different endpoints to get 

1) Current year's data
2) Filtered data for widget

Comment: response time will be the same, as you will make the same requests. The difference is that you manage the holidays in one state (reducer). You just append the new holidays to the list.